# Sed based on 2 words, then replace whole line with variable

Tags: linux, bash, sed, scripting, pattern-matching

I have a txt file looking like this,

```
1:Ana:apple:08:00:wait
1:Joe:banana:08:30:wait
1:Oscar:orange:08:45:ready
1:Monica:apple:08:50:ready
1:Mark::orange:ready
```

I have to find **only the first line** that contains both 2 words, **"banana" and "wait"** then **replace whole line** with **$myvar**

I have tried this code so far but i think i have some problems with matching 2 words at the same time.

```
sed -i "0,/banana.wait/c\$myvar" myfile
```

Thanks to anyone that can help me

Comment: Do you really need to be using sed for this?  Awk is much better suited to this task (even more so if you care which column each word is in).

Answer (score 7):

To let the `c` command only affect lines that contain both `banana` and `wait`, make sure to skip all lines that don't match these two patterns.  You may do this using the `b` command, which will branch to the end of the editing script for the current line:

```bash
sed -e '/banana/!b' -e '/wait/!b' -e "c\\$myvar" file
```

This skips the `c` command if the current line does not match either `banana` or `wait` (in any order).

If the order is important (`banana` before `wait`), then use

```bash
sed -e '/banana.*wait/!b' -e "c\\$myvar" file
```

If it's important to match whole words and not substrings (i.e. only `banana` and not `bananas`), then wrap each word in `\<...\>` or `\b...\b` to ensure that the word boundaries are properly matched.

Note the double backslash, which is how you insert a single backslash in a double-quoted string.  A single backslash would have escaped the `$` in `$myvar`, preventing the variable from being expanded.

Note that this requires a `sed` implementation, like GNU `sed`, which allows the text for the `c` command to be entered without a preceding newline character.

This furthermore assumes that any literal newline character in the value of `$myvar` is escaped with a literal backslash character, as in

```bash
myvar='hello\
world'
```

If the input data is structured into records with fields and if it matters what field is `banana` and what field is `wait`, then parse the records properly, possibly using `awk`, as in

```bash
value=$myvar awk -F : '$3 == "banana" && $NF == "wait" { $0 = ENVIRON["value"] }; 1' file
```

This explicitly tests the 3rd field for `banana` (an exact string test rather than a regular expression substring test), and the last field for `wait` and replaces the current record with the given value, passed in as the environment variable `value`.

Answer (score 1):

Frame challenge: sed isn't the best tool for this.

In Awk, we can combine matches disregarding order, i.e `/banana/ && /wait/`.

Or we can exactly match particular fields

```bash
awk -F: -v repl="$myvar" -e '$3 == "banana" && $6 == "wait" { $0 = repl } {print}'
```

Comment: Don't you just hate it when downvoters give you no hint what you could improve?

Comment: Indeed. Have an upvote to compensate. Btw if you put a space between `-v` and the variable name then it'll work in all awks, not just GNU awk, i.e. `-v repl=` instead of `-vrepl=`.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton - I didn't realise that the abutted argument was non-portable.